# Spreading a Column to Find Largest/Smallest Observations

Tags: r, spread

Currently struggling with a problem finding the country where billionaires are the oldest and youngest on average in a given country (data set shown below).

Moreover, I need to remove countries that have less than five observations.

I have code below that shows a table of age, worth in billions, and country code. I have countries sorted, but I am unsure of the best strategy to find which country has the youngest/oldest billionaires.

I have one line struck out where I am trying to spread by country name, but I think that will probably be messy.

Small sample here:

```
# A tibble: 2,614 x 22
     age category citizenship company.name company.type `country code` founded
   <int> <chr>    <chr>       <chr>        <chr>        <chr>            <int>
 1    NA Financi… Saudi Arab… Rolaco Trad… new          SAU               1968
 2    34 Financi… United Sta… Fidelity In… new          USA               1946
 3    59 Non-Tra… Brazil      Companhia B… new          BRA               1948
 4    61 New Sec… Germany     Ratiopharm   new          DEU               1881
 5    NA Financi… Hong Kong   Swire        new          HKG               1816
 6    NA Traded … Bahrain     YBA Kanoo    new          BHR               1890
 7    NA New Sec… Japan       Otsuka Hold… new          JPN               1921
 8    NA Traded … Japan       Sony         new          JPN               1946
 9    66 Financi… Japan       Mori Buildi… new          JPN               1959
10    NA Traded … France      Chanel       new          FRA               1909
# … with 2,604 more rows, and 15 more variables: `from emerging` <chr>,
#   gdp <dbl>, gender <chr>, industry <chr>, inherited <chr>, name <chr>,
#   rank <int>, region <chr>, relationship <chr>, sector <chr>, `was
#   founder` <chr>, `was political` <chr>, wealth.type <chr>, `worth in
#   billions` <dbl>, year <int>
```

```
dput(head(bil))
structure(list(age = c(NA, 34L, 59L, 61L, NA, NA), category = c("Financial", 
"Financial", "Non-Traded Sectors", "New Sectors", "Financial", 
"Traded Sectors"), citizenship = c("Saudi Arabia", "United States", 
"Brazil", "Germany", "Hong Kong", "Bahrain"), company.name = c("Rolaco Trading and Contracting Company", 
"Fidelity Investments", "Companhia Brasileira de Distribui?ao", 
"Ratiopharm", "Swire", "YBA Kanoo"), company.type = c("new", 
"new", "new", "new", "new", "new"), country_code = c("SAU", "USA", 
"BRA", "DEU", "HKG", "BHR"), founded = c(1968L, 1946L, 1948L, 
1881L, 1816L, 1890L), `from emerging` = c("True", "True", "True", 
"True", "True", "True"), gdp = c(1.58e+11, 8.1e+12, 8.54e+11, 
2.5e+12, 1.6e+11, 6.1e+09), gender = c("male", "female", "male", 
"male", "male", "male"), industry = c("Money Management", "Money Management", 
"Retail, Restaurant", "Technology-Medical", "Money Management", 
"Consumer"), inherited = c("True", "True", "True", "True", "True", 
"True"), name = c("Abdul Aziz Al-Sulaiman", "Abigail Johnson", 
"Abilio dos Santos Diniz", "Adolf Merckle", "Adrian and John Swire", 
"Ahmed Ali Kanoo"), rank = c(404L, 145L, 322L, 388L, 162L, 383L
), region = c("Middle East/North Africa", "North America", "Latin America", 
"Europe", "East Asia", "Middle East/North Africa"), relationship = c("founder", 
"relation", "relation", "relation", "relation", "relation"), 
    sector = c("construction", "investment banking", "retail", 
    "pharmaceuticals", "trading company", "shipping"), `was founder` = c("True", 
    "True", "True", "True", "True", "True"), `was political` = c("False", 
    "False", "False", "False", "False", "True"), wealth.type = c("self-made finance", 
    "inherited", "inherited", "inherited", "inherited", "inherited"
    ), worth_billions = c(1, 2.5, 1.2, 1, 2.2, 1), year = c(1996L, 
    1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), spec = structure(list(cols = list(age = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), category = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), citizenship = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), company.name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), company.type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), `country code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), founded = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), `from emerging` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), gdp = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), gender = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), industry = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), inherited = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), rank = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), region = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), relationship = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), sector = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), `was founder` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), `was political` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), wealth.type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), `worth in billions` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), class = "col_spec"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

```
load("bil.RData")
print(bil)

# Renaming a few columns for spacing issues
colnames(bil)[21] <- "worth_billions"
colnames(bil)[6] <- "country_code"

# Finding where billionaires are oldest/youngest on average, 
# ... then removing less than five observations
bil %>%
    filter(!is.na(age)) %>%
    select(age, worth_billions, country_code) %>%
    group_by(age, worth_billions, country_code) %>%
    mutate(count = n()) %>%
    arrange(country_code) %>%
    #spread(key = country_code, value = "USA") %>%
    print()
```

I expect to find the country that has the oldest billionaires and youngest billionaires, excluding countries with fewer than five observations. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: We don't have your `rdata` file to load it. You need to follow the steps provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the NA elements in 'age' (`filter`), grouped by 'country_code' and `filter` out the groups having less than 5 billionaires, then `summarise` the `mean` of 'age' and `slice` the row having the `max`imum value for 'ageMean'

```
library(dplyr)
bil %>%
   filter(!is.na(age)) %>% 
   group_by(country_code) %>%
   filter(sum(worth_billions) > 1.0) > 5) %>% 
   summarise(ageMean = mean(age)) %>% 
   slice(which.max(ageMean))
```

Comment: @PageSim Can you use `dput` to show the example.  Also, please check your previous question

Comment: Unsure if that dput output is helpful because I am unsure exactly what I am looking to glean from it.

Comment: @PageSim In your previous question, is that the expected output

Comment: @PageSim Your example breaks at `filter(n() > 5)`

Comment: I am really just looking for an output where I can see which country has the oldest billionaires on average without any countries that have five or less billionaires. Does that help?

Comment: @PageSim you meant the 'age' averaga per 'country' roight?

Comment: @PageSim Did you meant `bil %>% filter(!is.na(age)) %>% group_by(country_code) %>%  summarise(ageMean = mean(age)) %>% slice(which.max(ageMean))`

Comment: @PageSim I think the above woruld work.  you may have to use `filter` in between for the five or less billlionaries which should be from. `worth-billoions`

Comment: I think that is the one; sorry for the poor communication. I am quite new to R and need to learn a bit more about summarise, I think. Thanks again.